# How do I simulate a bitwise rotation of a 64-bit (unsigned) integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I need to perform a circular left shift of a 64-bit integer in JavaScript.  However:

- JavaScript numbers are doubles
- JavaScript converts them to 32-bit signed ints when you start with the << and the >> and the >>> and the ~ and all of the bit-twiddling business.  And then it's back to doubles when you're done.  I think.
- I don't want the sign.  And I definitely don't want the decimal bits.  But I definitely do want 64 bits.

So, how do I perform a bitwise left rotation of a 64-bit value?

Comment: Do you know for sure that your Javascript will always be running on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: p.s. Downvotes for anyone who tells me not to do this in JavaScript.  Not helpful!  And I *know* that this is not the sort of task that JavaScript is well suited for.  But I need to do it anyway. KTHXBAI.

Comment: not that I believe you, but if JavaScript stores it in a double then it's a double not a 64bit int (regardless of sign).

Comment: Sigh. This is why I used the word "simulate" in the question. I don't need JavaScript to store this as a single 64-bit int; I just need to do something that gives me the right answers when I say "circular left shift this value 35 places, and tell me what the resulting int value would be if we were playing with 64-bit ints."

Comment: So are you wanting to rotate the bit-level representation of a double (or just 64bits), or rotate the integer number that the double represents?

Comment: I want to rotate the integer number that the double represents.  Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear; what I want is to rotate a 64-bit unsigned integer.  I went into JavaScript's internal representation of numbers because I was thinking that the lack of distinction between floats and ints in JavaScript would make it harder to do what I want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep your 64-bit number as separate high and low partitions. To rotate left N when N < 32:

`hi_rot = ((hi << N) | (lo >>> (32-N))) & (0xFFFFFFFF)`

`lo_rot = ((lo << N) | (hi >>> (32-N))) & (0xFFFFFFFF)`

If N >= 32, then subtract 32 from N, swap hi and lo, and then do the above.

Comment: I like this way of doing it, but will the fact that the numbers are signed cause any gotchas?  The most significant bit stores the sign.

Comment: Oh, you said less than 32.  Looks like that takes care of the problem.

Comment: The only problem with this is that `& (0xFFFFFFFF)` is a no-op here. If you want to make the numbers unsigned, use `>>> 0` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I believe so, though not the most efficient way, convert the number to a string in binary form (64-bits), use substring to move the char at the beginning and append it to the end (for left rotation) and convert the binary form back to number. I am sure you can figure out how to convert a decimal number to its binary form into a string and back.

Comment: Nah, it's a legit solution, even if it's not the kind of solution I'm hoping for. No downvotes for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Doug Currie put it you need to represent the 64-bit number as two numbers, then do bit-wise operations on them.  The code I've used is:

```
//Constructor for a Long..
function Long(high, low) {
    //note: doing "or 0", truncates to 32 bit signed
    //big-endian 2's complement int..
    this._high = high | 0;
    this._low = low | 0;
}
Long.prototype.rotateLeft = function(bits) {
    var newHigh;
     if(bits === 32){ //just switch high and low over in this case..
        newHigh = this._low;
        this._low = this._high;
        this._high = newHigh;
    } else {
        newHigh = (this._high << bits) | (this._low >>> (32-bits)); 
        this._low = (this._low << bits) | (this._high >>> (32-bits));
        this._high = newHigh;
    }
    return this; //for chaining..
};
//Rotates the bits of this word round to the right (max 32)..
Long.prototype.rotateRight = function(bits) {
    var newHigh;
    if(bits === 32){ //just switch high and low over in this case..
        newHigh = this._low;
        this._low = this._high;
        this._high = newHigh;
    } else {
        newHigh = (this._low << (32-bits)) | (this._high >>> bits); 
        this._low = (this._high << (32-bits)) | (this._low >>> bits);
        this._high = newHigh;
    }
    return this; //for chaining..
};
```

To use it try running: `console.log(new Long(0,1).rotateLeft(4));` then inspecting the _high and _low properties.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think it can be done is to create an int64 class which internally contains two 32 bit integers and performs shifting by carrying between them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a values based rotate.

```
double d = 12345678901.0;
// get high int bits in hi, and the low in
int hi = (int)(d / 16.0 / 16.0 / 16.0 / 16.0);
int low = (int)d;

int rot = 3; // thus * 8
int newhi = (low >> (32 - rot)) | (hi << rot);
int newlow = (hi >> (32 - rot)) | (low << rot);

double newdouble = ((double)hi * 16.0 * 16.0 * 16.0 * 16.0) + (double)low;
```

Comment: Well that's a C# version, and because of the signed int's the last step does not actually work as expected. Infact it's most likely will also not work for negative doubles ether...

Comment: Using arithematic operation is kindly too slow, especially when you want to convert a large amount of bytes, e.g. image data, which is not a practical solution.